# DOM or SAX Parsing Example

Tags: android, dom, xml-parsing, sax

I've tried **every** tutorial I could on Google to parse my XML file (you can view it [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38725067/webexample/Site%203/index.xml)).

All I want to do with the file in the link above is parse it in an Android app and extract each String's name and string.

Could anyone help out here?  I've been through at least 7 or so tutorials and I'm losing all hope right now.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XmlPullParser for parsing XML.

For e.g. refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html

Comment: This example does not show me how to read XML from a URL.  It only shows how to write an XML file and then read it.

Comment: You can use the following code for that     URL url = new URL("http://-----");
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); conn.connect();
and the read the URL content by url.openStream())

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow when I get to my Mac.  For now, you receive my approved answer.

Comment: Nevermind, the problem is solved now, but thank you for your help :).

Answer (score 1):

JAXP:

JAXP stands for Java API for xml processing.
 It is a specification from w3c.
 JAXP is an API from SUN.

using JAXP api, we can process xml document in two mthods. 
 DOM:
Stores the entire xml document into memory before processing.
It occupies more amount of memory.
It traverse in any direction.
Tree data structure

Steps to work with DOM:

1. Create documentBuilderFactory

   DocumentBuilderFactory factory= 
   DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
2. Create DocumentBuilder

   DocumentBuilder builder=factory. newDocumentBuilder();

   1. get input stream      ClassLoader cls=DomReader.class.getClassLoader();
      InputStream is=cls.getResourceAsStream("xml file");     4.  parse xml file and get Document object by calling parse method
      on DocumentBuilder object.
      Document document=builder.parse(is);     5. Traverse dom tree using document object.SAX: 
      Simple xml parsing.
      It parses node by node
      Traversing is from top to bottom
      Low memory usage
      Back navigation is not possible with sax.

   //implementing required handlers 
     public class SaxParse extends DefaultHandler{      }      //new instance of saxParserFactory      SAXParserFactory factory=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    //NEW INSTANCE OF SAX PARSER      SAXParser saxparser=factory.newSAXParser();      //Parsing xml document
    SAXParser.parse(new File(file to be parsed), new SAXXMLParserImpl());